# MarketplaceService:PromptGamePassPurchase() player should be of type Player error shows up even though it is of type player

Tags: lua, roblox

I was scripting a simple donation button in Roblox so that if you clicked the button, it would prompt a gamepass to show up for you to buy. My current code looks like this:

```
local id = 139782763
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer


script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptGamePassPurchase(Player, id)
end)
```

Whenever I click the button though, it gives me this error:

```
 MarketplaceService:PromptGamePassPurchase() player should be of type Player
```

Why does this happen?

I tried to make a donation button but it gave me an error.

Comment: Your code looks reasonable. This is a LocalScript right?

Comment: @Kylaaa wait is there a difference between regular Script and LocalScript i dont know what that is im new

Comment: @Goudya see the documentation for [LocalScript](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/LocalScript) and regular [Scripts](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Script).

Comment: The reason why I asked about it being a LocalScript is because `game.Players.LocalPlayer` only exists in LocalScripts. In server-side Scripts, it is nil.